# Inside angle of a triangle with two sides of known ratio and one known side?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

This is my first question on here so please take it easy on me, my terminology is not the best and my geometry is rusty.

I have a triangle with the known base of L and one side of unknown length A and the other side of unknown length 3/5 A.

Can I find the alpha angle in terms of only the known L variable? 
If not can I find the alpha angle based on the known length L and unknown variable A?

The background of this question is finding the angle of the originating source of a signal with two sensors (not a school homework task). I'm trying to code this with python, though stuck in the math at the moment.

Many many thanks for your help!

[image]

EDIT:
Thank you for all your answers. I made this drawing to assist myself and anyone else looking at this in the future to understand that alpha changes with A or the radius of the bigger circle. Indeed alpha is dependant on A, yet a dependant of only A and L.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $\alpha$ is not independent from $A$. Think about attaching a string of any length $\frac{8A}{5}>L$ to the to endpoints of the base.

You can still find $\alpha$ in terms of $A$ and $L$ using

1. The [Apollonius' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem) to find the dashed length and
2. The [Law of Cosine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to find $\cos\alpha$, hence $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you I was able to find the value of alpha with those two laws above!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be independent of $A$, except in the very simple case where the two sides dependent on $A$ are both of length $A$ (isosceles). Let us suppose we have the general problem, where a triangle has one side of length $L$ and then two sides of lengths $A, kA$, and let us assume without loss that $k < 1$. The smallest we may let $A$ be is $L/(1+k)$, in which case we have a degenerate triangle, where $\alpha = 0$. However if we set

$$\frac{L}{1+k} < A < \frac{L}{1-k}$$

We have a nondegenerate triangle with $\alpha > 0$. If we make the fairly reasonable assumption that $\alpha$ depends continuously on $A$, then it cannot possibly be constant.

EDIT:  Another intuitive way to see this is that if you consider triangles with base as in your diagram and third vertex lying on the line creating angle $\alpha$, then as the distance from origin to third vertex grows very large, the two sides from base to third vertex should have ratio closer and closer to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't find α.

Assume L = 1.

Then we can consider three situations:

1. A is 5/8, so A + 3/5 A = 5/8 + 3/8 = 1; here, the objective point is directly between the two sensors.
2. A is 5/2, so A - 3/5 A = 5/2 - 3/2 = 1; here, the objective point is in line with the two sensors, and off to the right.
3. A is 5/4; in this case, 3/5 A = 3/4, so 3/5 A, L, and A create a 3-4-5 triangle, so the objective point is off the line, directly above the right sensor.

Comment: (by the way thank you for picking 3/5, it was remarkably convenient)